# calculate balance factors of nodes recursively only root is given and in a single pass

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures, python-3.x, binary-tree

---

the problem is we **shouldnt use any tree traversals**

> def fill_balance(root):
>
> > > > if root == None :
> > > >                 return None
> > > >         root.value = fill_balance(root.left)-fill_balance(root.right)

here is my code to calculate balance of each node of a tee whose root is given .. how can i fix my code ? ***the solution must be in a single pass***
root is generated and function must be recursive .

Comment: What do you mean by shouldnt use any tree traversals?

Comment: in order pre order or post order traversing to build the tree

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the solution:

```
def get_height(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        if node.height is None:
            node.height = max(get_height(n.left),get_height(n.right))+1
        return node.height

def fill_balance(node):
    if node == None:
        return
    else:
        node.balance_factor = get_height(node.left)-get_height(node.right)
        fill_balance(node.left)
        fill_balance(node.right)
        return

fill_balance(root)
```

Comment: this is the code when node is passed . aint i right ? it is not when root is passed into the function as a paramenter

Comment: look at the last line. you only need to call the function with root once. node is just the name for the argument.

Comment: yah .. i got it thnx a lot for the help

Comment: @Bharadwaj_Turlapati please accept the answer if it provided the correct solution